# How to convert an int to a string in DTrace?

Tags: freebsd, tracing, dtrace

I'd like to be able to concatenate a string and an int using `strjoin()`, e.g.,

```
strjoin("ada", args[1]->unit_number);
```

but in order to do that I have to make sure that the int is first converted to a string.

---

I'm running DTrace on FreeBSD 13.1-RELEASE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, there is an `lltostr()` that does that:

```
strjoin("ada", lltostr(args[1]->unit_number));
```